# Performance problem with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I make the following query. It is just too slow due to the amount of info being pulled out. First I pull some data and filter it out and store it for the second query inside the `filts` variable, and based on that pull other set of data from the database (Eager loading). Is there a way to perform this filtering without pulling all of this data first and then filtering it, for example maybe do it directly in the data base in some way? What is the normal way to do that? This query sometimes takes 15+ seconds. Specs contains around 100K entires and Insitutions about 30K. I need to get the query to work in less than half a second. `IncludeAction` indicates which foreign key items should be pulled with the item itself.

```
  var filts = new HashSet<int>(_uow.SpecialitiesRepository.GetAllAsQueryableAsNoTracking(IncludeAction<Speciality>.None)
                                       .Where(x => byPrice ? x.Price >= pl && x.Price <= pr : true)
                                       .Select(x => x.Id))
                                       .AsParallel(); 

  var query = _uow.SpecialitiesRepository.GetAllAsQueryableAsNoTracking(new IncludeAction<Speciality>(x => x.Include(t => t.Institution)))
                                         .Where(sp => filts.Contains(sp.Id))
                                         .AsParallel()
                                         .ToList() <--- this is needed in order to be able to use Institution in further filterings
                                         .Where(sp => byRegion ? sp.Institution.Region.ToString("G").ToLowerInvariant() != region.ToLowerInvariant() : true)
                                               && Institution.Countries[sp.Institution.CountryCode.ToLower()].Alpha2.ToLowerInvariant() ==
                                               lowerCountry : true)
                                         .AsParallel();
```

Comment: What does `GetAllAsQueryableAsNoTracking` do? Why `.AsParallel().ToList()`? This will load everything into memory and proceed to process the results there, withouth any benefit of indexing. It will *degrade* performance instead of increase it in several ways - first by loading a lot of unneeded data, then by crunching them without any indexing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hi thanks for answering, if i don't include that it doesn't load the Institution variable which is a foreign key to another table. I'm also using EF Core if that makes any difference..

Comment: Database string comparisons are case-*in*sensitive most of the time. This means that all those calls to `ToLower()` aren't needed. Database indexes are a lot faster than client-side dictionaries too, which means that joining with a `Countries` table on the server would be faster than the dictionary lookup too

Comment: it *will* load it if you actually use it in the rest query, or if you add an `.Include()` clause. EF Core doesn't change the fact that this query will load everything into the client's memory

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos okay so if I remove the call ToList() it would do the work on the database level? Your point about joining with a Countries table is good, does that mean this is also a cause for it to pull that data on the server?

Comment: 100K rows for a main table and 30K rows for a lookup table are actually *very few* rows. 15 seconds is a very long time. BTW loading the filters with a separate query is a bad idea too - this could be a simple JOIN on the server. Perhaps you should describe the *tables* and what you want the query to do, not what the LINQ query does

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes exactly, I've been pulling my hairs out because 100K is something that can in theory be loaded directly into memory -_-'

Comment: @Christo I don't know what your query does - the actual query is broken in two and hidden by multiple `AsParallel()`, `ToList()` and dictionary lookups. It's probably a lot easier to write a proper reporting query between the 3 (?) tables. It will be a lot faster too. Once you have that query you can decide whether you should use it as is, probably as a view or stored procedure, or if you need to recreate it in LINQ (probably *not*)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189488/discussion-between-christo-and-panagiotis-kanavos).